# Recovering Databases from replica

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, database-backups, database-restore

I have simple configuration - (MariaDB) slave and master.

Because Master had an accident I need restore databases from replica. But if im using mysqldump - sad no such database.

In replica server I can't list interested databases as well.

Comment: what about change the slave to master https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changing-a-slave-to-become-the-master/
you can revert them back

Comment: @justsomeone the OP said that the interested database it is not on the slave, so there is no point of changing, I think.

Comment: Please provide `show databases` on your slave and which one is the one you want?

Comment: i hope he just type his database name in wrong letter case that why it report it not exist as linux is case sensitive

Comment: what action did you perform on the master side? Hope you didn't execute like drop database.

Comment: No :) i didnt drop database. Just on my (master database) rasperry pi filseystem completely was crushed. I have backup but only from 2021/03. i want lose so many data. And im trying howto recover data from replica ...

Comment: BTW show databases; doesnt show databases from master.

Comment: What is wrong in command: CHANGE MASTER "malina.dom.pl" TO MASTER_HOST="raspi.dom.pl",MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='root', MASTER_USE_GTID='0-2-3652369',MASTER_LOG_FILE="mysql-bin.000127",MASTER_LOG_POS=76403202; ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.